# How to pass JqGrid data source (with applied filters) to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have defined the following button in jqgrid. I have looked up alot of posts regarding this but still cant figure out how to send the data source to controller (not the filters).

I need to somehow get the datasource as a collection in the controller

```
$("#btnExportCsv").click(function () {
            $.blockUI({ css: {
                border: 'none',
                padding: '15px',
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                color: '#fff'
            }, message: '<h1>Exporting to CSV</h1><p><img src="/cms/themes/cm-blue/img/busy.gif" /></p>'
            });

            generating = true;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: exportCsvUrl,
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $.jGrowl(XMLHttpRequest.responseText, { header: 'Error exporting csv' });
                    generating = false;
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $.unblockUI();
                },
                success: function () {
                    growl("Export completed successfully", "Export to Csv");
                }
            });

        });
```

---

jQGrid params:

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        colNames: [
    .
    .
    .  
        ],
        colModel: [...]
    mtype: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        pager: '#crPager',
        page: defaultGridParams.Page,
        sortname: defaultGridParams.SortName,
        sortorder: defaultGridParams.SortOrder,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
        url: Controllers/control,
        height: 'auto',
        loadui: 'block',
        width: 1200,
        caption: sGridCaption,
        hidegrid: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        ShrinkToFit: false,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should consider looking at the problem the other way around.
The grid got it's data from somewhere and I can gess it came from a controller.
If you need that data server-side, why don't you get it form the same method you used to populate the grid?

The only way I can see this not working is if the data is fed client-side to the grid and you have no way of getting that exact same data server-side.

Anyway, if you really want to get the data from the drid just call:

```
$("#mygrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
```

This returns json, so don't expect nothing more than that.
The kind and quality of that json structure deppends on the way you have your grid configured.